# Global variable without using sessionStorage in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a global variable called sessionId which is provided by a Node application. this variable is an eas-256 encrypted string.

```
sessionStorage.setItem('sessionid', apiResponse.credentials)
```

Im storing this variable on a sessionStorage now, but I dont feel confortable with that. I use that variable (which is pretty long) to send on the header of all http calls to the server and validate the user.

I do constants all the time on a globals.ts file I import later, such as

```
export const agencyid = 'eXrDOJ1zJYI='
```

But these are of course constants I cannot modify.

Is there a better way to store the member's logged information without using sessionStorage, or a way to keep a variable persistent while the angular application is still on the browser session? can this be done within the globals.ts file Im importing already on about 70 components?

Thanks.

Comment: How about storing it in a auth-service.ts ? It can send a GET request on app initaize to fetch these detais on app init (page reload), and then is responsibe for faciitating this info to all components / services via subject / observable ?

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. Will that be more secure that my current method? The variable is about 800 characters long, imposible to decipher, but I still feel uncomfortable displaying that information openly on the browser inspector.

Comment: Maybe my question should be more like, is it a standard practice to store this variable the way Im doing it?

Comment: TBH, anything that’s sent to client without SSL, can’t be considered secure. 

Anything that’s available at client, can be manipulated. I would rather have stored this id in cookie so that I can take help of standard server side cookie-id to session mapping where I securely store values in session.

Comment: You are sending this key every time you do a request, so it's not that important where you store it - since it's always visible. Besides you could implement an Interceptor and store there your token.

Comment: Yes Jacopo. Its a eas-256 encrypted key, about 800 characters long, that I send on every request I perform to the server (on the header).

Answer (score 0):

Well you could persist the sessionId as a simple variable in a (singleton) service, but I don't think it would make it any more secure and any refresh of the page would force you to login again.

Comment: Johan, Im not worried about security, I just feel uncomfortable displaying that variable on a sessionStorate. I will check singleton services and let you know :)